# How to create One to Many Relationship in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i was previously worked  relationship in laravel. so recently i moved to core php ,so i am trying for one to many relationship.but it always return separate record. 
i have following tables

**authors**

```
id | username | created_by | updated_by
```

**books**

```
id | author_id | book_name | book_image |
```

**Query**

```
select * from authors left join books  on author.id=books.author_id
```

i am looking my result somethink like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Norm

            [books] => Array
                (
                  [0] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 4
                    [book_name] => great wall
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )

                    [1] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 6
                    [book_name] =>new book
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Norm

            [books] => Array
                (
                  [0] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 2
                    [book_name] => amazing star
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )

                    [1] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 3
                    [book_name] =>way of journy
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )
                )

        )


but in core php i am getting  ouput


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => david
            [created_by] => 
            [user_id] => 1
            [books] => book1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [username] => david
            [created_by] => 
            [user_id] => 1
            [books] => book2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [username] => david
            [created_by] => 
            [user_id] => 1
            [books] => book3
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [username] => miller
            [created_by] => 
            [user_id] => 2
            [books] => new1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [username] => miller
            [created_by] => 
            [user_id] => 2
            [books] => new2
        )

)
```

so i want to display author name with many books.can any one help me,how i can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

```
class Author extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the books for the author.
     */
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
}

...

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the atuhor that owns the book.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

-- [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: hi i am looking core php query not laravel.

Comment: What do you mean with *core php*? Simple PHP with PDO?

Comment: @Krenor.yes simple php .